# binding instanciated property to UI

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have this class :

```
public class property : DependencyObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _myproperty;

    public string MyProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return this._myproperty;
        }
        set
        {
            this._myproperty = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("MyProperty");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string sproperty)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(sproperty));
        }
    }
}
```

In the main window I have created an instance of this class `myclass xx = new myclass();`, where I populate my property with string data and bind it to XAML like so:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:property x:Key="prop"></local:property>
</Window.Resources>
```

In my `TextBox` i have set the binding :

```
Text="{Binding Path=MyProperty, Source={StaticResource prop}}" BorderBrush="#FFC7CACC" />
```

This will not work unless if i use the existing resources:

```
var property = (local:property)Resources["prop"];
```

Is there another way to update the `TextBox` rather than using the resources? I want to use the normal class instantiation.

Comment: local:local:property?

Comment: there is only one loccal , sorry ,local:property....

Comment: Why are you using this property class as a resource? Just put MyProperty into the viewmodel for your UI and bind it from there

Comment: have tried this but with no luck

Comment: So no solution here!! This made me curious :D

Comment: yeap...so far no solution ^^

Answer (score 0):

if you say `Text="{Binding Path=MyProperty, Source={StaticResource prop}}" BorderBrush="#FFC7CACC" />`
means that your VM is an instance of property class.

Try to surround your textbox with a Grid and set the grid dataContext with an instance of your poperty clas.

I mean

```
<Grid DataContext="from view or from behind assign your vm= new property()">
 <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=MyProperty" ....../>
</Grid>
```

Comment: have tried this, but unfortunatly this is not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<Window.DataContext>
 <local:property/>
<Window.DataContext>

<TextBox Text="{Binding MyProperty}"/>
```

After setting the data context, just try to build the application, the build will succeed if it can find the **property** class in the **local** namespace.

After building your app, if succeeded, you can try to set the binding and also the Intellisense will automatically show MyProperty in Binding Options.

If this doesn't work, try to set the data context and binding using the Properties panel. Maybe visually you can get things right.

Try it, and if it fails, tell me where it went wrong